# Executing a python file in a module which is dependent on another module gives

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following project structure/files:

tests/mod1/test1.py
tests/mod1/test2.py
tests/unit_test_suite.py

tests and mod1 both have **init**.py file.

I have unit test classes in test1 and test2 files. With the unit_test_suite.py I want to run the tests in both files.

Contents of **unit_test_suite.py**:

```
import sys
import unittest

from tests.mod1.test1 import TestClass1
from tests.mod1.test2 import TestClass2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    tests = [TestClass1, TestClass2]
    for test in tests:
        suite.addTest(unittest.makeSuite(test))
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
    sys.exit(not result.wasSuccessful())
```

When I run `python3 -m tests.unit_test_suite` I get **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tests'**. I have verified that I executed this from the correct directory.

How do I get to run this?

Comment: Is the "tests" folder on the pythonpath? When you say the correct directory, can you be specific? This actually worked for me just now.

Comment: No, it is not. I am running this from the command line without modifying the pythonpath. My end goal is to run this in a jenkins job.

Comment: What is the correct directory?

Comment: The one where the tests module resides